# jquery validator need to submit twice

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-plugins, validation

I have to validated form with jquery validator plugin:

```
$("#efOptionsForm").validate({
    rules: {
        ef_main_bg: {
             accept: "image/*"
        }
    },
    errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox"        
});
```

This code shows error in div with id messageBox, if file is ok, it hides message but does not submit form. I need to click again to submit.

If i remove errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox", code works fine.

I have tried to add submit handler, like it it shown in manual, but nothing changes just console error.

```
$("#efOptionsForm").validate({
    rules: {
        ef_main_bg: {
             accept: "image/*"
        }
    },
    errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox",
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit(); // code shown in manual
    }
});
```

Does someone knows how to fix this?

BTW Form is located in Wordpress settings form if it changes something...

Edit: invalidHandler method works betted, just need to extract right information from object and hide default message tag.

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3L2tK/1/

Comment: Try to load pdf or other file and submit, then try jpg and submit again. Nothing happens after first click.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3L2tK/3/ - I think the problem when you select a file and then directly try to click the submit button the UI is changing because of the hiding of the error message...

Answer (score 0):

Today with some research managed to fix problem with another method:

```
$("#efOptionsForm").validate({
        rules: {
            ef_main_bg: {
                accept: "image/*"
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if (error) {
                $("#messageBox").html(error).wrap('<strong></strong>');
                $("#messageBox").show();
            } else {
                $("#messageBox").hide();
            }
        }
    });
```

Works fine for single error.